# PostgreSQL - Syntax error while assigning variable?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

This is my code:

```
amount INTEGER;

amount := select count(*) from moneyTable;
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:   syntax error at or near "select"
```

Can someone help me out.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @MrsEd im trying to store the number of tuples in the variable amount. Then use that variable later for other processing. But currently im getting that syntax error and I have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT):

> An assignment of a value to a PL/pgSQL variable is written as:
>
> ```
> variable { := | = } expression;
> ```

but `select ...` isn't an expression. If you want to assign values from a SELECT to variables, you want to use [INTO](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW):

```
select count(*) into amount from moneyTable;
--              ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Now im getting the error ERROR:   syntax error at or near " * ". CONTEXT: invalid type name "count(*) into amount from moneyTable"

Comment: Should work fine (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6558d/1 (sorry about the function formatting, sqlfiddle has problems with multi-line dollar-quoted strings it seems)). You're doing this inside a function, right?

Comment: I have it in the declaration part of my function

Comment: You should have that assignment in the body of the function. A bit of time with the PL/pgSQL documentation might be useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

Either the [@mu is to short](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33770199/131874) answer or this

```
amount := (select count(*) from moneyTable);
```